# How to partition my hard drive upon installing GNOME on a Ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning, gnome

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 and wish to install Ubuntu GNOME. I have an AIO Ubuntu iso written on a usb drive but am not terribly experienced with the partitioning set-up.

From either side (Ubuntu or GNOME) I wish to have access to my current Home directory. And I do not want to delete any files.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,

-MD

Comment: Have you looked at the option of just adding / installing the gnome desktop to your existing installation ? The you would avoid having to setup partitions, and you would have the same software in both desktops. If you do want to go the three partitions way (Home partition, and one for Ubuntu and Ubuntu GNOME respectively), you can do that too, how are your partitions setup currently ? Do you have a separate home partition ?

Comment: Not sure (but I think I do) if I have a separate home partition. How do I check this? Also, I have the iso files for this and many other Ubuntu de's so I want to "add" this to my system and being that this is what I have wanted to do it this way with this method. I am correct in saying that with the iso files I have to use this method? Also, I need to delete an installation of Elementary OS at the same time if possible.

Comment: You can check if you have a separate home partition by running `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` in a terminal - if you see a separate partition mounted at `/home` then you have a separate home partition. Yes, if you have an ISO file, it's an entirely separate distro, and you'll need to install it to a separate partition. You should be able to just have the installer install to the partition where Elementary OS is (check the "format" box in the installer), set  the installer to mount your  home partition at `/home`, and you should be good.

Comment: When I try to erase elementary and replace it with gnome it says no root system is defined?

Comment: Also not seeing /home just the following.  /dev/sda1.   /dev/sda3.   dev/sda6.   and.     /dev/sda5    where SDA 1 is elementary, SDA 6 is Ubuntu 16.10, and SDA 5 is swap.